# Use of proper noun District Attorney's Office or D. A.'s Office vs district attorney's office

Tags: proper-nouns

Is it correct to use the lowercase for district attorney's office when a particular office (e.g., Shelby County District Attorney's Office) is not included?

Even if you're referring to a particular DA's office in ongoing text, is lowercase still used since Shelby County doesn't directly precede it?

Answer (score 2):

My dictionary gives "district attorney" as lower case only. I'd leave it as lower case except when it's being used as a personal title (e.g., "District Attorney Smith") or part of an official name ("the Suffolk County District Attorney's Office"). If you've just used it as upper case and then use "District Attorney" to avoid repeating the whole phrase, consistency could justify capitalizing it, but I'd consider it optional in that case.

Comment: you can't know how appreciative I am for this clarification. Makes perfect sense and more importantly saves a lot of Find All, Replace with work.